# Cortana keeps launching without me meaning it to

Tags: windows-10, cortana

On my Windows 10 laptop, something I'm doing on the trackpad keeps inadvertently launching Cortana. I don't get it with an external mouse and there are no buttons on the pad so I'm wondering if it's a gesture recognition thing. It's VERY annoying - especially when I have music on and before I can cancel it it thinks the lyrics are a command and opens Internet Explorer!

Can anyone help? I don't want to disable Cortana, just stop it doing this one thing!!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which type of trackpad your laptop has, it's hard to say exactly what gesture is causing it. On my Synaptics trackpad a three finger tap will activate Cortana.

Commonly, the mouse/trackpad settings are under **Control Panel -> Mouse** (under "icons/classic" view). For Synaptics trackpads, there will be a "ClickPad" tab and then a button for "ClickPad Settings". This will pop-up a window with options for all the different gestures your pad supports.